# Convert rails application to exe file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any way to convert the Rails application to executable file ?

Please suggest me the solution or provide the link.

Answer (score 1):

To package your application you should take a look at http://phusion.github.io/traveling-ruby/